# Return Object from mongoose cannot be modified

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, post

I changed username property in data object to a value name.username in Nodejs, Bur Property value is not modified.
Would you pls explain why object is not modifying and a solution for this problem...

```
/ schema
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  }
})
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)
const excerScheme = mongoose.Schema({
  username:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User',
    required:true
},
  description:String,
  duration:Number,
  date:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now()
  }
})
const Excercise = mongoose.model('Excercise',excerScheme);
//Routes
app.post('/api/users/:userId/exercises',(req,res)=>{
  const newEx = new Excercise({
    username : req.body[':_id'],
    description : req.body.description,
    duration : req.body.duration,
    date : req.body.date,
  })
  newEx.save().then((data)=>{
    User.findOne({_id:data.username}).lean().exec().then((name)=>{
     //changed data.username
 data.username = name.username;
      
      
      return res.json(data)
//data is not modified
    })
    
    
  }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a `Excercise` document, and its `username` field should be a reference (stored as an `ObjectId`) to a `User` instance.

That means you can't assign any string to it, like you are trying (presumably to replace the `ObjectId` with the user's name for display purposes).

You have to convert the document [to a plain JSON object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-toJSON) first, then you can reassign `username`:

```
data = data.toJSON();
data.username = name.username;
```